# Which column compression type should i choose in amazon redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a table over 120 million rows.
Following command `analyze compression tbl;` shows `LZO` encoding for almost every VARCHAR field, but i think that `runlenght` encoding may be better for fields with finite number of options (traffic source, category, etc.).

So should i move certain fields to another encoding or stay with LZO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Thoughts on `runlength`

The point about `runlength`, rather than a finite number of options, is that field values are repeated over many **consecutive** rows. This is usually the case when table is sorted by that column. You are right, though, that the fewer distinct values you have, the more likely it is for any particular value to occur in a sequence.

#### Documentation

Redshift states in their [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Runlength_encoding.html):

> We do not recommend applying runlength encoding on any column that is designated as a sort key. Range-restricted scans perform better when blocks contain similar numbers of rows. If sort key columns are compressed much more highly than other columns in the same query, range-restricted scans might perform poorly.

And [also](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/lzo-encoding.html):

> LZO encoding provides a very high compression ratio with good performance. LZO encoding works especially well for CHAR and VARCHAR columns that store very long character strings, especially free form text, such as product descriptions, user comments, or JSON strings.

#### Benchmark

So, ultimately, you'll have to take a close look at your data, the way it is sorted, the way you are going to join other tables on it and, if in doubt, **benchmark the encodings**. Create the same table twice and apply `runlength` encoding to the column in one table, and `lzo` in the other. Ideally, you already have a query that you know will be used often. Run it several times for each table and compare the results.

#### My recommendation

Do your queries perform ok? Then don't worry about encoding and take Redshift's suggestion. If you want to take it as a learning project, then make sure that you are aware of how performance improves or degrades when you double (quadruple, ...) the rows in the table. 120 million rows are not many and it might well be that one encoding looks great now but will cause queries to perform poorly when a certain threshold is passed.